# How can we draw the graph of the function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

We have that the contiuous growth rate of a function $u(t)$ is given by $$w_u(t)=\frac{d (\ln u(t))}{dt}$$

I have found the continuous growth rate of the function $\phi (t)=\phi_0e^{at}, \ \phi_0>0, a\in \mathbb{R}$ :

$$w_{\phi}(t)=\frac{d\left (\ln \left (\phi_0e^{at}\right )\right )}{dt}=\frac{1}{\phi_0e^{at}}\cdot \phi_0ae^{at}=a$$

How can we draw the graph of the function $\psi (t)=\ln \phi (t)$ ?

Comment: If $\phi_0$ is constant then $\psi = \ln(\phi_0 e^{at}) = \ln \phi_0 + at$ - a straight line.

Comment: So, we don't use the continuous growth rate, do we? @Bacon

Comment: If you wish to sketch $\psi$ then it will be a straight line, if you take the derivative of this, you end up with a constant, $a$, which you've demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi(t) = \ln\phi(t)$ then

$$
\psi(t) = \ln\phi_0 + \ln e^{at} = \ln\phi_0 + a t
$$

This is a straight line with intercept $\ln\phi_0$ and slope $a$. Below there's a sketch

[image]

Comment: Ah ok... So, we don't use the continuous growth rate of $\phi$, do we?

Comment: You do, it just turns out that for this particular function $\phi$, the continuous growth rate happens to be a constant ($a$), and it is equal to the slope of the line $\ln\psi$

Comment: Slight typo on $\phi_0$ second line, I'll delete my comment after you rectified.

Comment: @Bacon Thanks, but please do not delete it, I was editing my answer when you posted you reply. You deserve credit for it

Comment: Ah the derivative of a function is the slope of the graph, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar Correct Mary, the gradient of the straight line is given by the first derivative.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you very much!! :-)